# Should I install an AAV to remedy a possible drain siphon?

Tags: plumbing

In our basement there's a laundry sink that connects to the main 4-inch DWV pipe below the concrete floor. There's a 10-ft sloping horizontal length of 1-1/2 copper pipe that turns down ~90 degrees and disappears  down into the concrete floor over near the main 4" vent pipe. So it is connecting to it below the trap weir, as in the diagram. I imagine there's a 4x4x1-1/2 tee in the concrete floor where the copper line meets and is sealed with lead and oakum. Other drains in the house use that approach.

I don't know if there's a siphon happening, but I am considering retrofitting an AAV mid-run on near-vertical pipe in case there is, roughly per [this diagram](https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/plumbing/maximum-length-for-fixture-drains_o) which shows a vent preventing siphon. My AAV would be perched at the top of a near-vertical pipe so it's sitting an inch or two above the top of the sink.  Is there any reason that would be a bad idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Drain vents are commonly required to be within a short distance of the fixture. 10 feet certainly violates that principle (if not specific local code), so additional venting would be appropriate.

Instead of an AAV, though, which is a bit of a hack, consider boxing the vent to the 4" stack from near the sink, or run a new vent all the way up. (I've done so in a corner of a coat closet.) If an AAV is your only option, give it a try. Worst case you have to cap it.

All that said, you haven't indicated that there's an actual problem. I'd wait until you detect sewer gas leakage (or monitor the trap) before spending time and treasure on a *maybe* problem.

Comment: The vent is iron pipe so I can't really tie into it, and there's no access above. An AAV is the only feasible hack.

Comment: I see relatively inexpensive gas detection devices. Can they detect sewer gas?

Comment: You _can_ tie into iron pipe. I've done it myself for a basement laundry similar to yours. The right saw and a pair of shielded no-hub couplers and you're in business.

Comment: Your nose will detect sewer gas. It should be easy to check the trap and do some testing, though.

Comment: This 4" iron pipe goes up from the basement and out the roof (two-storey house).  Isn't that a lot of weight to transfer to the horizontal pipes attached to it when a section is cut out and replaced with rubber?

Comment: I mean even after the rubber coupling is installed, the horizontal pipes are now bearing weight they hadn't been.

Comment: Horizontal pipes? We have some serious confusion here. You cut out a section of pipe (with the stack temporarily supported), slide two couplers on the stubs, and fit new pipe with a sanitary tee between the stubs. Nothing changes with respect to weight.

Comment: You might ask a new question about your specific scenario if this is an avenue you'd like to explore.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were recommending to slip a rubber tee onto the stack in place of the cut-out secction.

Comment: That's not a thing. (I stand corrected. They _do_ make rubber sanitary tees in that size. For some reason. They're not appropriate here.)